# PHP mail function not working

Tags: php, wamp

I have written a basic script for the mail functionality.
I am trying to run this script through WAMP server.

```
<?php
phpinfo();

$to = "mss@xyz.com";
$subject = "Test mail";
$message = "Hello! This is a simple email message.";
$from = "mohan.s@xyz.com";
$headers = "From: $from";
$res= mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
echo " $res Mail Sent.";
?>
```

I have set the SMTP, sendmail_from in the php.ini file . 
It gives me the following error

> Warning: mail() [function.mail]: Failed to connect to mailserver at
>   "mucse409.eu.xyz.com" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port"
>   setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in C:\wamp\www\email.php on line 9
>   Mail Sent.

I am able to ping the SMTP address from my machine. Please guide me.

Comment: it could be that the mail provider is blocking your request. to check that use gmail SMTP since, as far as I know, gmail won't block you.
here is gmail SMTP settings:
smtp.gmail.com
port:465 or 587

Comment: its giving the same error 

Warning: mail() [function.mail]: Failed to connect to mailserver at "smtp.gmail.com" port 465, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in C:\wamp\www\email.php on line 8
Mail Sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following  this tutorial I was able to send mail [link text](http://blog.levhita.net/2008/03/13/send-email-using-gmail-and-phpmailer/).

> Send email using Gmail and PHPMailer The new automatic update
>   generator is ready, it has been a long time since OCRALight has been
>   finished and little bit of this and that has been polished on the
>   update generation.
>
> The process is fairly complex, it involves reverse-engineering,
>   data-mining, packaging, distribution and a lot o fighting with our
>   crappy Windows server that is between me and the final Linux
>   liberation.
>
> Every step in the road has been automatized, one by one, every problem
>   has been solved and polished, now the final piece is in his place, the
>   automatic email generation. Now the updates will be made and send
>   everyday, even weekends and vacations.
>
> If you are interested in the technical aspect keep reading:
>
> How it has been done:
>
> First of all, you need to have PHP with OpenSSL support, for Windows
>   you’ll need to Install PHP and carefully select OpenSSL in the
>   components list, if you already have PHP installed, don’t worry a
>   re-install will keep your configuration, and you’ll be able to select
>   OpenSSL.
>
> Then download PHPMailer,&nbsp; and extract it near your main php
>   file.
>
> You will need to have a Gmail account(obviously) I recommend you to
>   make a new one just for this, mainly because the configuration need to
>   be very precise, and you wouldn’t be able to use it freely without
>   loosing functionality or risking to break the configuration.
>
> Configure your Gmail account to use POP mail, but not IMAP, ONLY POP,
>   just POP.
>
> And now the code:

```
<?php
require(”PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php”);
$update_emails = array(
    ‘Juan Perez’ => ‘Juan_Perez@jalisco.gob.mx’,
    ‘Francisco Garcia’ => ‘fgarcia@hotmail.com’,
    ‘Diana la del Tunel’ => ‘diana@gmail.com’
  );

echo “\nSending Update Email\n”;

$mail = new PHPMailer();  // Instantiate your new class
$mail->IsSMTP();          // set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;   // turn on SMTP authentication
$mail->Host = “smtp.gmail.com”; // specify main and backup server
$mail->SMTPSecure= ’ssl’; //  Used instead of TLS when only POP mail is selected
$mail->Port = 465;        //  Used instead of 587 when only POP mail is selected

$mail->Username = “youremail@gmail.com”;  // SMTP username, you could use your google apps address too.
$mail->Password = “yaourextremelynotlamepassword”; // SMTP password

$mail->From = “youremail@gmail.com”; //Aparently must be the same as the UserName
$mail->FromName = “Your name”;
$mail->Subject = ‘The subject’;
$mail->Body = “The body of your message”;

foreach ($update_emails as $name => $email) {
  $mail->AddBcc($email, $name);
}

if(!$mail->Send())
{
  echo “There was an error sending the message:” . $mail->ErrorInfo;
  exit;
}
echo “Done…\n”;
?>
```

> In this code I send the email to a group of people, thus I use the
>   “Bcc:” field instead of the “To:” one, to add a “To:” you would use
>   AddAddress($email, $name).
>
> A possible upgrade would be to use a MySQL database to store the
>   addresses,&nbsp; and provide a web interface to add and remove
>   them. for the moment, this is enough.
>
> Soo remember:
>   PHP with OpenSSL; PHPMailer; Create a Gmail Account; Activate POP Host:
>   smtp.gmail.com; SMTPAuth=true; SMTPSEcure=ssl; Port: 465; User with Domain;
>   Password; $Mail-&gt;send();

Answer (score 0):

Can you also send mail from this machine to this smtp server using some mail client like ms outlook or mozilla thunderbird?

I had a problem once that my provider block traffic directed at smtp ports outside due to virus infection, and I couldn't send mail because of this, but I could ping server and port.

Comment: I can send through MS outlook from the same SMTP server.

Answer (score 0):

Could be blocked by a firewall or some such.

See if you can open port 25 with telnet (If you don't have software for this, you can download putty)

Comment: I am not able to open my SMTP server address nor smtp.gmail.com( port 465/587 ) .Does this mean firewall is blocking ?

Comment: Yeah, the simple way to test if it's your local firewall, is to try that port on other systems, where you know it's open.

Most likely a firewall of some kind. Look at any firewall or antivirus type programs on your computer, and on your router if you're behind one.